# A word for a relationship in which one thing (or state) must exist in order for another thing (or state) to exist

Tags: single-word-requests

I can't think of the word to fill this blank:

> More importantly, now we've got ourselves an "organic" roadmap—that is, one that follows the natural order of our concerns, rather than a logical order such as ____.

Though unrelated to my context, an example of such an ordering would be:

1. a bride and groom
2. a wedding
3. a wedding cake

A wedding cake wouldn't exist without a wedding, which in turn wouldn't exist without its bride and groom. (I'm sorry, the real example is technical and complex, and I can't think of a better example at 3 in the morning.)

I want to say *predecession* but that's not a real word. Does anyone know the word I'm looking for?

Comment: Okay, I can see that if we're being pedantic, a wedding cake may exist outside of a wedding, and a bride and groom is really only a bride and groom in the context of a wedding. Regarding the latter, we can say I mean _a couple_. Regarding the former, let's just try to understand what I mean :-)

Comment: Co-existant? Co-dependent?

Comment: I thought of, simply, _dependence_, and technically that works, but for some reason I'm convinced there's a word that starts with a 'p'. (But it may not after all.)

Comment: Perhaps, contingent?

Comment: @JasperLocke - Oh, that's a great one! I'd upvote if you posted it.

Comment: *Sine qua non* is worth a mention here because it's a common phrase that has the meaning specified in the title of the question; it wouldn't really work in the example sentence, though, because it's not an ordering system.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A *prerequisite* is something that must exist for another to exist.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I think that's it—and it was so obvious! Let me wait a few more hours though, in case someone comes up with a word that strikes even truer to me.

Comment: In the software world (and especially in the world of build systems), *prerequisite* and *dependency* are (often) complementary terms, so the latter is probably worth mentioning here.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps, contingency/contingent? Maybe this definition for contingency:

> a future event or circumstance that is possible but cannot be predicted with certainty

and this one for contingent:

> occurring or existing only if (certain other circumstances) are the case; dependent on

EDIT: I just thought of this one after I had posted, but it could also be conditional.

> subject to one or more conditions or requirements being met; made or granted on certain terms

Answer (score 4):

Given the statement "Logically, *A* can't exist or occur without *B*", then to describe *A* 's relationship to *B*, you'd say "*A* is a **prerequisite** of *B*" (as @JasperLoy  answered).

By contrast, if you wanted to describe *B* 's relationship to *A*, you'd say "*B* is **predicated** on *A*" (which sounds a lot like your "*predecession*" to me).

Answer (score 3):

> **Anaclitic** - Relating to or characterized by a strong emotional dependence on another or others.
>   As defined by [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/anaclitic).

In psychology, we use it to define the relation you described, often with features or symptoms like "anaclitic happiness" or "anaclitic pain."

But it can be extended to non-emotional features in informal conversations.

The noun "anaclisis," however, broadly means a relationship characterized by the strong dependence of one person on others or another. It encompasses physical and non physical features or status.

Comment: I think if you were to use the word "anaclitic" in a conversation, all you would get would be blank stares.

Comment: More likely a mix of blank stares and suppressed snickers.

Answer (score 3):

There is a Latin term used by English speakers, **sine qua non.** Translated literally, it means something like "without which not."

Answer (score 1):

I agree that *prerequisite* is the best fit, but instead of *predecession*, *predecessor* is likely the word you were missing.

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer is a good fit for your title question, it doesn't seem to quite match the blank.

It isn't a single word, but in your example, I would fill the blank with *a predetermined sequence*. Alternatively either *a determined sequence* or *a contingent sequence*.

Answer (score 1):

Amazingly the mathematical phenomenon 'mutually exclusive' (meaning that if A= B, B does not necessarily equal A), exists only if A cannot exist without B..? You think?

Comment: = does actually mean B equals A, we have A **implies** B doesn't mean B implies A, for example all tomatoes are red doesn't mean all red things are tomatoes. (i know tomatoes can be green...)

Comment: No I don't think.  "Mutually exclusive" is not a mathematical phenomenon.  Mathematically, if A=B then B=A due to commutativity.